# HTML sub-menu disappearing on hover after added CSS caret

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, caret

I have added a CSS caret to "Right-A" menu from the example below (or see https://jsfiddle.net/z44kz1nk/) . If you hover on "Right-A", and try to click on any item in the sub-menu, you will see the submenu getting disappear.

It looks right the error is caused by the gap in the caret, but I can't find a solution now.

```
<nav>
            <ul class="inline-menu left-menu">
                <li><a href="">Left-A</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Left-B</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="inline-menu middle-menu">
                <li><a href="">Middle-A</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Middle-B</a>
                    <ul class="open-right">
                        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="inline-menu right-menu">
                <li><a href="">Right-A</a>
                    <div class="caret"></div>
                    <ul class="sub-menu-full-width">
                        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Right-B</a>
                    <ul class="open-right">
                        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-height: 1.25em;
}

nav{
    text-align: center;
}

/* menu */
.inline-menu,
.inline-menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.inline-menu.left-menu{
    float: left;
}

.inline-menu.right-menu{
    float: right;
}

.inline-menu.middle-menu{
    display: inline-block;
}

.inline-menu > li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 100px;
}

.inline-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* sub-menu */
.inline-menu > li > ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid #eee 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 60px;
}

.inline-menu > li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}

.inline-menu > li:hover > ul.sub-menu-full-width{
    width: 100%;
}

.inline-menu > li:hover > ul.open-right{
    right:0px;
}

.inline-menu > li:hover > ul > li:hover{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* caret */
.caret {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.caret:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #807979;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  display: none;
}

.inline-menu > li:hover .caret:before{
    display: block;
}

.caret + ul{
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Caret is creating a gap between sub-menu and main menu till your mouse pointer leaves and main menu and reaches sub-menu the sub-menu already gets hidden

if you want to keep the caret at same position as it is now in your example then write code to show the sub-menu on hover of caret as well

check https://jsfiddle.net/atalkishore/z44kz1nk/1/

**Change the code for caret as**

```
<li><a href="">Right-A<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-full-width">
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: There is another gap in your example, https://jsfiddle.net/atalkishore/z44kz1nk/1/

Comment: which gap you are talking about can you elaborate or post some image

Answer (score 1):

You Can put carot inside the li like this

```
 <nav>
            <ul class="inline-menu left-menu">
                <li><a href="">Left-A</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Left-B</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="inline-menu middle-menu">
                <li><a href="">Middle-A</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Middle-B</a>
                    <ul class="open-right">
                        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="inline-menu right-menu">
                <li><a href="">Right-A</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu-full-width">

                        <li  class="caret" style="padding-top:10px"><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Right-B</a>
                    <ul class="open-right">
                        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: I prefer to have better HTML.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML sub-menu disappearing on hover after added CSS caret**
Make div.caret same width as the submenu you are targeting.

As html **hover effects**, by default undo themselves once the cursor doesnt focus the **target element**, So in this case when you hover the caret everything is working as u want, **but when u hover the otherside of the caret**, nothing shows up because the **width** of the caret is really narrow;
**please make the width of the caret the same as the target to achieve your goal**, Hope it helps

Comment: Can you show actual code please? I got lost on what you are saying.

Comment: increasing the width of caret will make caret look ugly

Comment: The caret has a transparent background. But I meant there is a big between the caret and the actual hover parent  Element.